# Flyspell breaks on special characters

Tags: flyspell

## Problematic Behavior

Special characters appear to split words in `flyspell` even if the words are in my dictionary:

[image]

How can I fix this?

## Flyspell Configuration Details

I am using the `ispell` backend for Flyspell. I have added these words to my `ispell-personal-dictionary`. Adding words without special characters to my personal dictionary works just fine.

Comment: You need to give much more information. For example does your flyspell use aspell, ispell, etc. What are your dictionary settings? You mention "my dictionary" - is this a personal dictionary and where is it located? Etc. Etc.

Comment: m43cap, you're perfectly right. When I posted this question I did not appreciate the complexity of `flyspell`. It is a proper framework with pluggable parts, which means that one user's environment may behave quite differently from another. I have resolved this problem for myself by switching to `hunspell`, which does not break on special characters (although annoyingly it _does_ break on apostrophes in my setup). To improve this question's quality however, I will `git checkout` my setup at the time of posting and add more information accordingly.

Comment: I'm pleased you've solved the problem - great!

Comment: I think I'm having the same problem as Matthew (post-upgrade):  Flyspell seems to be breaking words on apostrophes, so that e.g. `doesn't` results in `doesn` being highlighted as a spelling error.   I too am using `hunspell` on OS X.  The only spell-check-related configuration options I've set (that I know of) are:

```(setq-default ispell-program-name "/usr/local/bin/hunspell") \n (setq ispell-really-hunspell t)```.
Any suggestions?

Comment: @EricAnderson I ran into this issue too when configuring spellcheck this week - ended up adding a line into `ispell-dictionary-alist` - see https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/78599/flyspell-and-or-ispell-hunspell-quirk-for-contraction-words-shouldnt-isnt -- hope it helps if it's still causing you issues.