# Flyspell and/or ispell + hunspell: Quirk for contraction words (shouldn't, isn't etc. getting flagged)

Tags: flyspell, ispell, spell-checking, hunspell

When setting up my spell-checking with flyspell and hunspell, contractions such as `shouldn't` and `isn't` are getting flagged:

[image]

I believe it's not (entirely) the dictionary's issue (en_GB) as when I type in `shouldnt` the suggestion (from `ispell-word`) for `shouldn't` still comes up:

[image]

After accepting `shouldn't` and taking the cursor off it, the word gets flagged up again:

[image]

I'm not sure where in the flyspell/ispell/hunspell stack this can be addressed. The issue still occurs if I use backtick instead of single quote.

Answer (score 0):

After digging around the ispell source (https://github.com/emacs-mirror/emacs/blob/master/lisp/textmodes/ispell.el), narrowed down the issue to `(ispell-get-word 'f)` returning `shouldn` when it should have been returning `shouldn't`; its docs suggested customising this behaviour using `ispell-dictionary-alist`.

A code search on GitHub suggested adding in something like `'("en_GB" "[[:alpha:]]" "[^[:alpha:]]" "[']" nil ("-d" "en_GB") nil utf-8)` to the list, which I've also had to do after flyspell-mode is activated, so overall something like this fixed it for me:

```
(defun my/fix-ispell-contraction ()
  "Fixes contractions (e.g. shouldn't) aren't not being checked properly.
See https://github.com/casouri/lunarymacs/blob/master/star/checker.el#L44-L49."
  (add-to-list 'ispell-dictionary-alist
               '("en_GB" "[[:alpha:]]" "[^[:alpha:]]" "[']" nil ("-d" "en_GB") nil utf-8)))

;; Flyspell
(use-package flyspell
  :ensure nil
  :config
  (add-hook 'flyspell-mode-hook 'my/fix-ispell-contraction)
...
```